# How to scan for an image before Findfailed prompt

Tags: java, python, sikuli, sikuli-script

here is what I need to do. Please let me know what I should add or change.

Problem: In the task I'm having, sometimes there is a random popup with a slider. When this pops up, Sikuli will throw a `FindFailed` exception. Instead I would like this script to scan for an image and do the slide action and then retry looking for what it was looking for before. I'm pretty sure it's just a couple of lines I need to add at the top of the code.

Example: let's say if it can't find `5.png`, it will throw a prompt asking for user input. Instead, I want it to search for the image then do a slide action and then start looking for image `5.png` again and continue.

Code below:

```
Region(example Region)
setFindFailedResponse(PROMPT)
Settings.MoveMouseDelay=0
click("1.png")
click("2.png")
click("3.png")
click("4.png")
click("5.png")
click("6.png")
click("7.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a loop that detects if a certain pop-up appeared. 
For example you could make it look if the pop-up header is present. 
When that is `True` you can use `PopUp = App.focusedWindow()`. 
Then `PopUp` is the region defined, exactly the pop-up only.

Then make a picture of the slidebar, if that one is visible within `PopUp` you can use 'mouseDown()' and `mouseUp()`. 
Then look again if that image exists.

For looking if an image exists or not you can use:

```
if exists(image5): 
    # Do something
else:
    # Do something else
```

For looking for an image within the Pop-up window you could use:

```
if PopUp.exists(imageScrollbar): 
    # Do something
```

When I make Sikuli use the scrollbar I usually make a picture of the 3 stripes on the scrollbar.